# VBA UPDATE query. Set NULL fields to a valuse

Tags: vba, updates

I'm trying to run a update command for the following:
In a table called **t_AuditCompliance_import**.
If a field called **"Payable Time Entered By"** is Null, update the NULLs to say "exception".

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE t_AuditCompliance_import SET t_AuditCompliance_import.[Payable Time Entered By] = ("exception")" _
         & "WHERE (((t_AuditCompliance_import.[Payable Time Entered By]Is Null));"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE t_AuditCompliance_import SET t_AuditCompliance_import.[Payable Time Entered By] = ""exception"" " _
     & "WHERE (((t_AuditCompliance_import.[Payable Time Entered By] Is Null));"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no space between ] and Is, plus you need a space at the start of your WHERE clause.  Should be

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE t_AuditCompliance_import SET t_AuditCompliance_import.[Payable Time Entered By] = ("exception")" _
& " WHERE (((t_AuditCompliance_import.[Payable Time Entered By] Is Null));"
```